# How to swap items in a VBA scripting.dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary

I need to swap entries in a VBA scripting.dictionary.  Why is this code failing?

```
Code:  `Option Explicit

Sub playWithGroup()
    Dim Data As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Data.Add key:="a", Item:="A"
    Data.Add key:="b", Item:="B"
    Data.Add key:="c", Item:="C"
    Data.Add key:="d", Item:="D"
    Data.Add key:="e", Item:="E"
    Data.Add key:="f", Item:="F"

    For i = 0 To Data.count - 1
        Debug.Print Data.keys()(i) & "  " & Data.items()(i)
    Next i
    Debug.Print ""

    k = Data.keys()(1)
    Data.keys()(1) = Data.keys()(3)
    Data.keys()(3) = k

    Debug.Print "k: " & k
    For i = 0 To Data.count - 1
        Debug.Print Data.keys()(i) & "  " & Data.items()(i)
    Next i
    Debug.Print ""
End Sub
```

Output in the Immediate window:

```
a  A
b  B
c  C
d  D
e  E
f  F

k: b
a  A
b  B
c  C
d  D
e  E
f  F
```

`

Comment: Carriage returns didn't display as I intended, hope it still makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The [Keys() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etzd1tzc(v=vs.84).aspx) returns an array which contains the keys. You are modifying this returned array and then instantly discarding the array and hence its modifications. Each call to `Keys()` returns a brand-new array, which is based on the unmodified dictionary.

To swap elements in the dictionary, the most natural way is to directly use the keys:

```
k = Data("b")
Data("b") = Data("d")
Data("d") = k
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!